# how to parse xml to get specific nodes having particular value for an attribute

Tags: python, perl, shell

In the below xml using perl or python(which ever is fastest) I want a way to get all  nodes/node names that have attribute1 set to "characters" and  attribute2 not set to "chr" or dont have attribute2 itself .
Please keep in mind that my xml can have 500 nodes,so kindly suggest a faster way to get all nodes

```html
<NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="chr" name="node1">
  <content>
    value1
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera"  name="node2">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera" attribute2="car" name="node3">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>
```

Comment: Hello. Usually it's asked of users that they at least give a sample of what they've done so far in solving a problem.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is a xpath expression:

```
//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]
```

quick test with xmllint:

```
kent$  cat f.xml
<root>
<NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="chr" name="node1">
  <content>
    value1
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera"  name="node2">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera" attribute2="car" name="node3">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>
</root>

kent$  xmllint --xpath '//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]' f.xml
<NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="chr" name="node1">
  <content>
    value1
  </content>
</NODE>
```

### UPDATE

if you only want to extract the value of attribute `name`, you can use this xpath:

//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]/@name

or
    string(//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]/@name)

still test with xmllint:

```
kent$  xmllint --xpath '//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]/@name' f.xml                                                          
 name="node1"

kent$  xmllint --xpath 'string(//NODE[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2="chr")]/@name)' f.xml
node1
```

Comment: Can you plz give me xpath where it will print only names of the nodes

Comment: @Dilip updated the answer, now the xpath extracts only the value of attribute `name`.

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged this as perl/python, I shall offer a perlish approach.

Perl has a nice library called [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) which I really like for parsing XML.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $parser = XML::Twig->new();

#would probably use parsefile instead.
#e.g.:
# my $parser = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
{
    local $/;
    $parser->parse(<DATA>);
}


#iterate all the elements in the file. 
foreach my $element ( $parser->root()->children() ) {

    #test your conditions
    if ($element->att('attribute1') eq 'characters'
        and ( not defined $element->att('attribute2')
                       or $element->att('attribute2') eq 'chr' )
        )
    {
        #extract name if condition matches
        print $element ->att('name'), "\n";
    }
}


__DATA__
<DATA>
  <NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="chr" name="node1">
    <content>
      value1
    </content>
  </NODE>

  <NODE attribute1="camera"  name="node2">
    <content>
      value2
    </content>  
  </NODE>

  <NODE attribute1="camera" attribute2="car" name="node3">
    <content>
      value2
    </content>
  </NODE>
</DATA>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `lxml` module.

```
content = """
<body>
<NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="chr" name="node1">
  <content>
    value1
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera"  name="node2">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="camera" attribute2="car" name="node3">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="characters" attribute2="car" name="node3">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

<NODE attribute1="characters" name="node3">
  <content>
    value2
  </content>
</NODE>

</body>
"""

from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(content)
l = root.xpath('//*[@attribute1="characters" and ( not(@attribute2) or @attribute2!="chr") ]')
for i in l:
    print i.tag, i.attrib
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 
NODE {'attribute2': 'car', 'attribute1': 'characters', 'name': 'node3'}
NODE {'attribute1': 'characters', 'name': 'node3'}
```